# Had a big file in git that is now smaller, git thinks its still too big

Tags: git, github

I had a big file in git that was > 100 Mb. Now its down to 70Mb or so but the file name is the same. I can't change the file name.

I tried

```
git rm --cached filename
git add filename
git commit
```

It still thinks the file is too big.
How do i tell git to refresh the file size?

error message is:

> remote: error: File "filename" is 138.99 MB; this exceeds GitHub's
>   file size limit of 100.00 MB

Comment: It would be helpful if you included the error message you're getting. Git doesn't normally reject files of that size; chances are something else is involved.

Comment: Updated with error message

Comment: Can you add this as new file name if possible

Comment: I can not change the filename if that is what are you asking

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a limit from your hosting provider (Github). They are checking not just your current set of files but also the versions in previous commits (remember Git keeps a copy of every version of each file, even the ones deleted in recent commits).

To get this to work you're going to have to remove or change the file in all of your previous commits, too. If it's just a few commits, you can use [interactive rebase](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Tools-Rewriting-History) and do it manually for each commit, otherwise you can use the `filter-branch` tool. There are some examples of using it to remove files in the official manual: https://git-scm.com/docs/git-filter-branch

Comment: Thank you Jan Kruger, that did indeed fix my problem.